# Gradle Project Issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

[Gradle project sync falied... this error is show by android studio since I got an update to Android Studio 2.1 along with the NDK error. Whether I am creating new project or opening old project, the code is red each time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT8th.png)

When I updated my Android Studio from 2.0 to 2.1, the code of all the project got red and Gradle Sync Error occured along with the NDK toolchain folder error. while creating XML layout, the design is also not displayed by the android studio.