# Gradle Project issues

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error each time I try to do any work on Android Studio 2.1 and everything in each activity become red. How can I resolve this issue??
I am getting these errors.
**1.**Error:No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi . 
**2.**Gradle project sync falied. Basic functionalities may not work properly

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKiSH.png)

Comment: Please include the error you are getting for anyone to respond in context.

Comment: Error:No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi
.
Gradle project sync falied. Basic functionalities may not work properly,

Comment: well whenever trying to ask such type of questions, do remember the exception is only helpful if you add the implementation. I am pretty much sure the exception mentions the line number and its in build.gradle file.
I cn only guess what the issue here is since you are not providing enough information. Looks like you are passing wrong ABI info to the ndk .
For anyone to answer the question here first share your build.gralde. then also add the exact stacktrace in the question ..you can edit it .so go give it a try.

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanRana Typically, people post their code in text form; it makes it easier to copy/paste and test it (nobody wants to type everything by hand). If it's impossible to add the code or output as text, at least add the image to the post rather than linking to it; that way, the post will still make sense if the link stops working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Project Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964683/gradle-project-issue)